# multilevel page table

Tags: linux, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

have 2 questions :

1. A computer with 32-bit address uses 2-level page table (9 bit top level and 11 bit second level). How many much is the size of the page, amount of page in address space, and the minimum size of page table that should reside in the memory ??
2. A 32-bit virtual address space computer has 4 KB pages. texts and data get into the lowest page (0-4095). Stack is at the highest page. How many entries needed if the computer still use  traditional page table and 2-level page table (10 bit each for PT1 and PT2)?

THX for the answers guys....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `9 bit + 11 bit = 20 bit`. Given this, it lets 12 bit for offset, which is basically a 4kb page. The top-level *page-directory* stores 256 page-table entries, and the second-level *page-table* stores 2048 page entries.
2. From a user point of view, you need 2 or three pages (*stack, code+data*, or *stack, code, data* if you have differents pages for code dans data, i.e. the data page has a no-execute attribute). From a memory manager point of view you need one more page to store the *page-directory* structure, and one or two more pages to store the corresponding *page-tables* strucuture. First entry of the *page-directory* points to the *page-table* page holding the entries for code and data pages. The last entry of the *page-directory* points to the *page-table* holding the entry for the stack page.

Hope this help.

Comment: thx benoit, it really helps... can u explain what is the 2-level page table used to in question 2 ?

Comment: Page-directory refers to the top level page-table of your first bullet, page-tables refers to your second-level. Thus we have page-directory->page-table->page. This is the x86 paging. I guess your question 2 refers to this model, you should take a look at the [Intel manua](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/253668.pdf).